# Splitting two words in excel

Tags: excel

Spliiting Words together in a pair like (Head LM) from other word in a cell in Excel

[image]

```
                                                                        Name        Role
John Dowe (Head LM); Moniq Jamese (Lead JK); Larrye Stuarte (Front TR)  John Dowe   Head LM
```

I need to be able to split [Head LM] from the rest of the text without the parentesis, just Head LM. I tried several options like:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(S3," ",REPT(" ",100)),300)) 
=RIGHT(S3, LEN(S3)-FIND(" ", S3,1)-5)   =>resule is :  (Lead PM); J
```

In both instances the text isn't clean from the () and other words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `A1` contains:-

```
John Dowe (Head LM); Moniq Jamese (Lead JK); Larrye Stuarte (Front TR)
```

This:-

```
=LEFT(MID(A1,FIND("(",A1)+1,LEN(A1)),FIND(")",MID(A1,FIND("(",A1)+1,LEN(A1)))-1)
```

returns:-

```
Head LM
```

For clarification:-

`MID(A1,FIND("(",A1)+1,LEN(A1))` finds the part of A1 that starts after the first (

`FIND(")",MID(A1,FIND("(",A1)+1,LEN(A1)))` works out the number of characters to the second )

`LEFT({...first snippet...},{...second snippet...}-1)` trims off the second )

**Update to handle all names/titles**

```
A1  your example text
B1  =LEFT(A1,FIND(";",A1))
C1  =LEFT(B1,FIND(" (",B1)-1)
D1  =MID(B1,FIND("(",B1)+1,FIND(")",B1)-(FIND("(",B1)+1))
E1  =MID(A1,LEN(B1)+2,FIND(";",A1)+3)
F1  =LEFT(E1,FIND(" (",E1)-1)
G1  =MID(E1,FIND("(",E1)+1,FIND(")",E1)-(FIND("(",E1)+1))
H1  =MID(A1,LEN(B1)+2+LEN(E1)+1,LEN(A1))
I1  =LEFT(H1,FIND(" (",H1)-1)
J1  =MID(H1,FIND("(",H1)+1,FIND(")",H1)-(FIND("(",H1)+1))
```

`B1` pulls the first name block (up to the first semi-colon)

`E1` pulls the second name block (up to the second semi-colon)

`H1` pulls the third name block

`C1`, `F1`, `I1` pull the name from their respective block

`D1`,`G1`,`J1` pull the title from their respective block

Any columns that are not required can be hidden - leaving just the required ones visible.  Breaking out the three blocks into `B1`, `E1` and `H1` make the formulae in the other cells simpler - but could be avoided, by substituting (for example) the formula in `B1` wherever `B1` appears in the other formulae (though this, obviously, makes those formulae even more complex).  This would then remove the need to hide any unwanted columns - as you would only calculate the values you require.

Comment: Thanx dav1dsm1th! It worked perfectly without any extra steps or cleaning. It's exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: you're welcome.  thanks are always nice (as are reputation points and closed questions...)

Comment: @user2980049 if this has answered your question, please do consider marking it as "Accepted".

Comment: THANKS ALL for the recommendations and quick responses.

Comment: If i want to segragate the 2nd name and role, also the 3rd name and role in separate columns? What'd be the best approach?

Comment: is it always 3 records in the string?

Answer (score 2):

This assumes that you want to get ALL of the words in parentheses, not just the first occurrence (this was not really clear in your question, so I assumed you were interested in all of them).  To do this, you'll need to split that cell using Text-To-Columns or something of that nature, so that your formula only has to deal with one name/title at a time. Then copy/transpose it so that each name/title is in its own row.

That done, you can use a formula like:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("(",A1,1)+1),"(",""),")","")
```

Here is a picture:

[image]

If you don't need ALL of the titles in parentheses, then you could obtain only the first instance without doing any Text-to-Columns/additional steps/etc. as per @dav1dsm1th's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Split this into a number of smaller problems so it makes sense.

To find the beginning of the word, first find the open paren

`=FIND( "(", A1 )`

To find the end of the word, find the close paren that follows your open paren

```
=FIND( ")", A1, FIND( "(", A1) )
```

So with these worked out, you can find your word. It starts 1 character after the open paren and goes for the length between the two minus that 1 character.

```
= MID( A1, FIND( "(", A1 ) + 1 , ( FIND( ")", A1, FIND( "(", A1) ) - FIND( "(", A1 ) ) - 1 )
```